# Sorting a two dimensional string list python

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort by the second element in a two dimensional list, where all the elements are strings.
It seems one of the problems with my current sorting method is that it cannot sort string elements. How would I go about changing it to integer?
If possible, I would also like to have the first element correlated to the highest second element printed out. '2001' in this instance.

```
sqrm_price= [['1999', '7951'], ['2000', '8868'], ['2001', '12502']] 


def highPrice(sqrm_price):
    sort_price = sorted(sqrm_price, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    print("The year " + sqrm_price[-1] + " has the highest price with " + sort_price[0] + "$")      
        
highPrice(sqrm_price)
```

My preferred output would be " The year 2001 has the highest price with 12502$"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `sorted(sqrm_price, key = lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to an integer inside your lambda using `int()`. Also, why `sort` when you can `max`?

```
def highest_price(data):
    year, price = max(data, key=lambda item: int(item[1]))
    print(f"The year {year} has the highest price with ${price}")
# The year 2001 has the highest price with $12502
```

Comment: I am new to pyhton and haven't heard about the 'max' method before, but it works very well. Thanks alot for your help!